# Trouble understanding this zener clamp circuit

Tags: gpio

So i'm getting there, as far as learning this stuff.  One part that has me stumped is voltage surrounding a zener diode.

My plan is to read a wiegand number from a card reader safely by dropping the 5v pins to 3v using the zener clamp shown here http://www.daycounter.com/Circuits/Level-Translators/Level-Translators.phtml

My question is, why is the gpio input wired to the TOP of the diode, and not on the other side?  Isn't the voltage along the top still 5v even with the resistor?

What confused me was this page which shows reduced voltage only on the opposite side of the diode after passing through.  http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode29.gif

So why does it work?

My plan sofar here is

 `5V - 330 R (1/4 watt okay?) - | - gpio 
                               |
                             3.3 zener
                               |
                              ---`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zener will break over at 3.3v on the "top" (cathode) side relative the anode, if the anode is connected to ground it will reduce any voltage on the cathode to 3.3v. However if the anode is connected to a non-ground voltage it will reduce the cathode side voltage to 3.3v + the anode voltage.

The resistor is a current limiter for the zener, so if the input voltage is 5v and the zener is dropping 1.7v then we do some math. V=I*R, so if you want say 20ma of current we have 1.7=0.02*R, rearrange to 1.7/0.02=R and we get 85 ohms. Now watts = V*A, which would be 1.7*0.02 = 0.034 watts. So in your case the 330, 1/4 watt will be more than sufficient.